# align left in IE only only on contact form page in Drupal Doctype?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal

I am building this site for a friend, every page looks correct but in IE it is floated left, causing the banner to repeat and text to look off center. The problem is in IE 7, 8 and 9.
http://www.tripodi.devserver2012.com/content/contact-us

there is no difference in the css between the other pages and this, the only difference is an extra class in the html but there is not css for this class. the whole  is off and here it the css it.

I think it has something to do with the doctype declaration.

Comment: jsfiddle.net or add here `html code`.

Comment: Looks like quirks mode is being triggered which is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is triggering quirks mode. Try removing anything before your DOCTYPE declaration, specifically: `<!-- Contact Us template-->`.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes):

> Quirks mode in any version of IE will also be triggered if anything
>   precedes the DOCTYPE. For example, if a hypertext document contains a
>   comment or any tag before the DOCTYPE, IE will use quirks mode